# Unable to install Google App Engine for Php in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: php, google-app-engine, protocol-buffers

I downloaded the [Google App Engine SDK for PHP](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_PHP) but I am having problems with the installation of the PHP interpreter. I downloaded the source code from the link given but when I try to compile `php` the command `make` terminates with this error:

```
 /bin/bash /home/david/Google/appengine-php-master/php-src/libtool --silent --preserve-dup-deps --mode=compile cc  -Iext/jsonc/ -I/home/david/Google/appengine-php-master/php-src/ext/jsonc/ -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/david/Google/appengine-php-master/php-src/include -I/home/david/Google/appengine-php-master/php-src/main -I/home/david/Google/appengine-php-master/php-src -I/home/david/Google/appengine-php-master/php-src/ext/date/lib -I/home/david/Google/appengine-php-master/php-src/ext/ereg/regex -I/libxml2 -I/home/david/Google/appengine-php-master/php-src/ext/sqlite3/libsqlite -I/home/david/Google/appengine-php-master/php-src/TSRM -I/home/david/Google/appengine-php-master/php-src/Zend    -I/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden  -c /home/david/Google/appengine-php-master/php-src/ext/jsonc/json.c -o ext/jsonc/json.lo 
In file included from ext/jsonc/json-c/json_inttypes.h:5:0,
                 from ext/jsonc/json-c/json_object.h:16,
                 from ext/jsonc/json-c/linkhash.h:16,
                 from ext/jsonc/json-c/json.h:22,
                 from /home/david/Google/appengine-php-master/php-src/ext/jsonc/json.c:34:
ext/jsonc/json-c/json_config.h:2:23: fatal error: ../config.h: No such file or directory
 #include "../config.h"
                       ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:725: recipe for target 'ext/jsonc/json.lo' failed
make: *** [ext/jsonc/json.lo] Error 1
```

In fact there is no such `config.h` file in that directory so I can't understand how to solve this problem.

So I decided to search online the source code of PHP 5.4.19 and I compiled and installed it and everything worked. I followed all the other installation steps and everything worked. 
Now if I start the server with the command

```
 google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/usr/local/bin/php-cgi --php_gae_extension_path=/home/david/Google/appengine-php-extension-master/modules/gae_runtime_module.so my_app/
```

I get:

```
 INFO     2016-03-25 15:04:19,209 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2016-03-25 15:04:19,797 sdk_update_checker.py:257] The SDK is up to date.
INFO     2016-03-25 15:04:19,901 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:51913
INFO     2016-03-25 15:04:19,907 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2016-03-25 15:04:19,909 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2016-03-25 15:04:21,270 php_runtime.py:348] The PHP runtime is not available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/david/Google/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 344, in new_instance
    self._check_binaries(php_executable_path, gae_extension_path)
  File "/home/david/Google/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 286, in _check_binaries
    cls._check_gae_extension(php_executable_path, gae_extension_path, env)
  File "/home/david/Google/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 241, in _check_gae_extension
    ext_stdout))
_PHPEnvironmentError: "/usr/local/bin/php-cgi -m" returned an error [-6]
[libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:61] This program requires version 3.0.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is 2.6.1.  Please update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "/home/david/Google/appengine-php-extension-master/remote_api.pb.cc".)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
  what():  This program requires version 3.0.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is 2.6.1.  Please update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "/home/david/Google/appengine-php-extension-master/remote_api.pb.cc".)
```

Accordingly to the message the problem should be in the version of `libprotobuf9` library. I have that library installed in my system (ubuntu 15.04) and in fact the version is 2.6.1. But by following the installation steps I installed `protoc-3.0.0-beta-2-linux-x86_64` and `protobuf-3.0.0-beta-2` in `/usr`. So, why does appengine use the wrong version of the library? 
I thought about removing `libprotobuf9` from my system but if I run `sudo apt-get remove libprotobuf9` the list of packages that need to be removed is very big and contains things like

```
 gnome-bluetooth gnome-calculator gnome-contacts
  gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer gnome-keyring gnome-mahjongg gnome-mines gnome-orca gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver
  gnome-screenshot gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra gnome-sudoku gnome-system-log gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal
```

to me it doesn't seem a good idea to remove them. What's the solution to my problem?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for installing from source? What's wrong with the version available in the Ubuntu package repository?

Comment: @Chris If you are talking about PHP the only supported versions are 5.4 and 5.5, while `apt-get` would install PHP 5.6

Comment: That's odd. I'm running 5.6 with the dev_appserver no problem.

Comment: I tried what you suggested with php 5.6.4. Now  dev_appserver.py says `_PHPEnvironmentError: Unable to load GAE runtime module at /home/david/Google/appengine-php-extension-master/modules` even though the file is there. Such file was generated by the old PHP so I followed again the steps given [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-extension) but at `make` it stops with `gae_runtime_module.cc:59:37: fatal error: ext/sockets/php_sockets.h: No such file or directory
 #include "ext/sockets/php_sockets.h"`. I ran `make` inside appengine-php-extension-master folder

Comment: I have managed to compile it by copying the folder `/usr/include/php5/ext` inside `appengine-php-extension-master` folder. `make` terminates with `Build complete. Don't forget to run 'make test'` Now if I run `make test` it says `PHP Fatal error:  PHP Startup: Unable to load users's php.ini due to missing application base dir` I think this error could be related to the error thrown by `dev_appserver.py`, but how do I solve it?